# Creating 2 Conditions to match the between value and copy

Tags: excel, vba

I have created this code but unable to complete it. I am trying that if 3.61 is > Col"E" Values and < Col"F" Values then copy the value for same row from Col"J" and Paste into A1.

[image]

```
Sub Macro1()
 Dim noRows As Integer
 Dim myRange As String
 Dim thisvalue As String
 
 thisvalue = 3.61
 
 noRows = Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
 myRange = "A6:V" & noRows
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(myRange).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">" & thisvalue, Field:=6, Criteria2:="<" & thisvalue
 
 'Then copy Col"J" same row value and paste into Sheet1.Range("A1")
 
End Sub
```

Here is my second try receiving an error that `Compile Error: Next Without for`

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim thisvalue As String
thisvalue = 3.61

 With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lLastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    vColT = .Range("E7:E" & lLastRow).Value
    vColU = .Range("F7:F" & lLastRow).Value
    
    For i = 7 To lLastRow
    
        If vColT(i, 5) > thisvalue And vColU(i, 6) < thisvalue Then
        

    .Range("J7:J" & lLastRow).Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
        Next i
End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim thisvalue As Double`, then `Criteria1:=">" & thisvalue`, then `Criteria2:="<" & thisvalue`. Variables belong outside quotes and are concatenated with `&`.

Comment: It hides the all value in filter using this `Field:=5, Criteria1:=">" & thisvalue, Field:=6, Criteria2:="<" & thisvalue`

Comment: You may have your `>` and `<` reversed then.

Comment: In reverse same result is appear. Is there another way achieving this where we can compare `thisvalue` between 2 value if it exists then copy value from other column.

Comment: What is your current code? Edit your question to show what you have now.

Comment: I just have the above code @ dbmitch

Comment: So you haven't made the changes from @BigBen? You must get an error?

Comment: No, I have made the chnages what BigBen suggested i do it. no error appear filter hides all the values

Comment: Flip the `>` and `<` and add `Operator:=xlAnd`.

Comment: Before initiating the code https://ibb.co/jyJ4xq1 after initiating the code https://ibb.co/ZLyJVtB

Comment: Second attempt: missing `End If`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code. You cannot paste the filtered rows as you intend doing...

```
Sub Macro1__()
 Dim thisvalue As Double, sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long
 
 thisvalue = 3.61
 Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")
 lastR = sh.Range("J" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arr = sh.Range("E7:J" & lastR).Value
 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    If arr(i, 1) < thisvalue And arr(i, 2) > thisvalue Then arrFin(i, 1) = arr(i, 6)
 Next i
 sh.Range("A7").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Comment: Add some type of explanation to explain what is different from his failing code and what you are doing to solve the error

Comment: Can you please give me one more favor that is how to create loop @FaneDuru if i have multiple values in Sheet1 Column A that i want to match one by one through above code and paste its result in Column B. Right now above code is working for single value.

Comment: I have added new [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68837793/creating-a-loop-to-go-through-each-value-in-range) please look into this

Comment: @Valiant Without explaining the context, I cannot supply a general answer about "multiple values"...

Comment: right now `thisvalue = 3.61` it goes for single values that is `3.61` and returns single value by matching the criteria. Suppose i have this `3.61` value in `Range(A2)` and there are more values in `A3,A4,A5 and so on` which result i want as well ib B2

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you're trying to combine two column filters in one AutoFilter

You need to add another Autofilter for your second column

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(myRange)
    .AutoFilter field:=5, Criteria1:="<" & thisvalue
    .AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=">" & thisvalue
End With
```

Your added code doesn't line up with your problem description.

All I can suggest is a solution for what I think you're wanting to do - fill in column A with values from column J when criteria filters are matched.

```
' Copy Filtered values in J column to A column
For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("J7:J" & noRows).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Debug.Print cell.Row
    Range("A" & cell.Row).Value = cell.Value2
Next
```

Comment: You are right thank you so much. can you please add one more thing that is to copy the same row value from Column J and paste in A1

Comment: How to make this like OFFSET(,1).copy @dbmitch

Comment: You're continuously adding code and questions to your initial question. I think you've discovered the Excel limitation that you cannot paste to cells in a range that contains hidden rows or columns. I would post your updated code and attempted effort to a new question that asks for help on the code you've tried. There is sample code at the end of the article https://spreadsheetplanet.com/paste-filtered-column-skipping-hidden-cells/

Comment: I added code for your second question. Hopefully one of the answers counts as one answer

Comment: Thank you very much i understand the mistake where i was lacking.