# Creating a loop to go through each value in range

Tags: excel, vba

I have below code in which i want to create a loop for multiple values that are available in `Sheet1.Range(A2:A100)` code will pick one by one each value and match then paste result in Column B.

`thisvalue = Sheet1.Range("A2:A100")`. Can someone please help me to create the loop. Your help will be appreciated.

```
Sub Macro1()
 Dim thisvalue As Double, sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrFin, i As Long
 
 thisvalue = 3.61

 Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet1")

 lastR = sh.Range("J" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 arr = sh.Range("E7:J" & lastR).Value

 ReDim arrFin(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr)

    If arr(i, 1) < thisvalue And arr(i, 2) > thisvalue Then arrFin(i, 1) = arr(i, 6)
 Next i

 sh.Range("B2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value = arrFin
End Sub
```

Comment: At first sight, `UBound(arr)` should be `UBound(arr,1)`  being two dimensional array .. Similarly, `UBound(arrFin)`

Comment: @Naresh  `UBound(arr)` is the same as `UBound(arr, 1)`. It returns the array number of rows.

Comment: @FaneDuru, yes learnt that:) Thanks.

Comment: The philosophy of the code should be changed a little. The actual code returns an array (`arrFin`) which rewrite the column A:A, keeping only the values which match the necessary condition. But, isn't it possible that more conditions from that big range (A2:A100) to be met by more cases? Should it remain the last occurrence?

Comment: `Sheet1.Range(A2:A100)` where `thisvalue` is supposed to be compared is nowhere in the code?

Comment: Please, check the code I posted. But I am not sure that you imagine what will happen. Or me... The process is dynamic and you can see only what remained after overwriting everything during the loop. But, I hope you know what you want...

Comment: Can you please look into this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68849656/comparing-three-columns-and-copy-pasting-data?noredirect=1#comment121681100_68849656) @FaneDuru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub Macro1__2()
 Dim thisvalue As Double, sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long
 Dim arrVal, arr, arrFin, i As Long, j As Long
 
 Set sh = Worksheets("Sheet2")
 arrVal = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("Q2:Q100").Value
 Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R2:R200").ClearContents
 
 lastR = sh.Range("J" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 arr = sh.Range("E7:J" & lastR).Value
 
 For j = 1 To UBound(arrVal)
    thisvalue = arrVal(j, 1)
    If CStr(thisvalue) <> "" Then 'excluding the cases of empty cells. I didn't know that they may exist
        arrFin = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R2:R200").Value 'firstly input the existing range in the array
        For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
           If arr(i, 1) < thisvalue And arr(i, 2) > thisvalue Then arrFin(j, 1) = arr(i, 6)
        Next i
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("R2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value = arrFin
    End If
 Next j
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for being late @FaneDuru but its not working i have attached above sheet please look into this. Thanks.

Comment: @Valiant Please, try the updated code. Since, I do not understand too well which are your expectations, I cannot state that it works as you need... You can download from [here](https://easyupload.io/g2pgt3) the processed workbook, using the above code.

Comment: Thank you very much @FaneDuru you always helped me beyond the way thank you. Here is the last [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836593/matching-two-string-with-2-columns-then-copy-dates-and-match-in-table) which sums up the whole help you give me. You have understand all. I would humble request you to please see this question.

Comment: @Valiant I've just optimized a little the above code, in terms of being faster. I did not know that empty cells will exist in the range to take `thisvalue` and now skipped that cells from iteration. I will look to your question, but not right now. I am a little busy...

Comment: It is skipping the values @FaneDuru https://ibb.co/PZ09kQY can you please look into this.

Comment: IT is skipping the values i do not know why. @FaneDuru https://ibb.co/PZ09kQY can you please check it.

Comment: Here is the updated sheet where it does not work for all values [sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g_fP0yNH1SoD4XeaKAK11cHHaiap0avY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Valiant I told you: I do not have any idea about what the code has to return. I only followed your explained request. If I will look to the file, I do not want consuming time to deduce what it is wrong. Please, state where to look and what to check! What it should be and why against what it is, or it is not... "does not work for all values" says NOTHING! I will not even download it if you do not clarify **what is to be checked**. I do not know what you try accomplishing!

Comment: @Valiant I tried checking the first pseudo problematic value: In "R10" it couldn't return anything for `3.3` value in "G10". **because the rules you set does not match**. There is not cases when "E:E" value is bigger than `thisvalue` and "F:F" is less than `thisvalue`. You should rething the rules, putting something like `>= thisvalue`!

Comment: Thank you so much @FaneDuru. I was unable to get this thing thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

### Ranges and Arrays

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const slrCol As String = "J"
    Const sCols As String = "E:J"
    Const sfRow As Long = 7
    Const scColLess As Long = 1
    Const scColGreater As Long = 2
    Const srCol As Long = 6
    Const sCriteria As Double = 3.61
    
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "B2"
    
    ' Create a reference to the Workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Create a reference to the Source Worksheet ('sws').
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    ' Create a reference to the Source Range ('srg').
    If sws.Columns(sCols).Columns.Count < srCol Then Exit Sub ' too few columns
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, slrCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If slRow < sfRow Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim rCount As Long: rCount = slRow - sfRow + 1 ' for source and destination
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = sws.Rows(sfRow).Columns(sCols).Resize(rCount)
    
    ' Write the values from the Source Range
    ' to the Source Array ('sData').
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    ' Define the Destination Array ('dData').
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Write the appropriate values from the Source Array
    ' to the Destination Array.
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To rCount
        cValue = sData(r, scColLess)
        If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
            If cValue < sCriteria Then
                cValue = sData(r, scColGreater)
                If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
                    If cValue > sCriteria Then
                        dData(r, 1) = sData(r, srCol)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Worksheet ('dws').
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    ' Create a reference to the Destination Range ('drg').
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfCell.Resize(rCount)
    ' Write the values from the Destination Array
    ' to the Destination Range ('drg').
    drg.Value = dData
    
    ' Clear the Destination Clear Range ('dcrg'),
    ' the range below the Destination Range.
    Dim dcrg As Range
    Set dcrg = drg.Resize(dws.Rows.Count - drg.Row - rCount + 1).Offset(rCount)
    dcrg.Clear ' or maybe rather 'dcrg.ClearContents'
    
    ' Format the Destination Range.
    'drg.Font.Bold = True
    'drg.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    'drg.Interior.Color = 14348258
    
    ' Save the workbook.
    'wb.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for being late. The code is just go for single value whereas it should go for multiple values one by one. I have attached a sheet above.