# Comparing Three Columns and Copy Pasting data

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below code which is comparing three columns values and copy pasting the 4th column data into other column.

My code is working fine but it is slow to perform the processing and takes much time and sometimes `Not Responding` window appears.

Any help to fix the problem will be appreciated

```
Sub rowMatch()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet3")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Dim a As String, b As String, c  As Date
    For i = 3 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 14).End(xlUp).Row

        a = ws.Cells(i, 14).Value
        b = ws.Cells(i, 15).Value
        c = ws.Cells(i, 16).Value

        For j = 3 To ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 98).End(xlUp).Row
        
            If ws2.Cells(j, 98).Value = a _
               And ws2.Cells(j, 103).Value = b _
               And ws2.Cells(j, 114).Value = c _
               Then
                ws2.Cells(j, 120).Value = ws.Cells(j, 18).Value
            End If
        Next j

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you do this, using an `=IF()` worksheet function?

Comment: Data is around 10K where in some cells i need to compare and copy paste for specific values not for all thats why cannot use.

Comment: You will want to bulk assign the data to variant arrays, then loop the variant arrays outputting the data into another variant array.  Then bulk assign the output array back to the work sheet.  looping worksheet ranges is slow.

Comment: I do no have much expertise to go with arrays. therefore i used loop.

Comment: @Valiant See the late Chip Pearson's article on [VBA Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).  Processing this way will be almost an order of magnitude faster!

Comment: Yes it will definitely thank for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A 'Triple' Lookup

- When in a loop a condition **1.** is not met or **2.** is met, use `Exit For` to stop looping (to exit the loop).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TripleLookup()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet3" ' Worksheet Name
    Const sfRow As Long = 3 ' First Row
    Const slColsList As String = "N,O,P" ' Lookup Columns
    Const slrCol As String = "N" ' Last Row Column
    Const svCol As String = "R" ' Value Column
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet2" ' Worksheet Name
    Const dfRow As Long = 3 ' First Row
    Const dlColsList As String = "CT,CY,DJ" ' Lookup Columns
    Const dlrcol As String = "CT" ' Last Row Column
    Const dvCol As String = "DP" ' Value Column

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, slrCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If slRow < sfRow Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = slRow - sfRow + 1
    Dim slrrg As Range: Set slrrg = sws.Cells(sfRow, slrCol).Resize(srCount)
    
    Dim slCols() As String: slCols = Split(slColsList, ",")
    Dim cUpper As Long: cUpper = UBound(slCols)
    Dim sData As Variant: ReDim sData(0 To cUpper)
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To cUpper
        Set srg = slrrg.EntireRow.Columns(slCols(n))
        sData(n) = srg.Value
    Next n
    Set srg = slrrg.EntireRow.Columns(svCol)
    Dim svData As Variant: svData = srg.Value

    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dlRow As Long: dlRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dlrcol).End(xlUp).Row
    If dlRow < dfRow Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = dlRow - dfRow + 1
    Dim dlrrg As Range: Set dlrrg = dws.Cells(dfRow, dlrcol).Resize(drCount)
    
    Dim dlCols() As String: dlCols = Split(dlColsList, ",")
    Dim dData As Variant: ReDim dData(0 To cUpper)
    
    Dim drg As Range
    For n = 0 To cUpper
        Set drg = dlrrg.EntireRow.Columns(dlCols(n))
        dData(n) = drg.Value
    Next n
    Dim dvData As Variant: ReDim dvData(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Loop
    
    Dim tUpper As Long: tUpper = cUpper + 1
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim dr As Long
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        For sr = 1 To srCount
            For n = 0 To cUpper
                If StrComp(CStr(sData(n)(sr, 1)), CStr(dData(n)(dr, 1)), _
                        vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then ' ignoring case
                    Exit For ' 1. mismatch found, no need to loop anymore
                End If
            Next n
            If n = tUpper Then ' no mismatch, all are equal
                dvData(dr, 1) = svData(sr, 1)
                Exit For ' 2. value written, no need to loop anymore
            End If
        Next sr
    Next dr
    
    ' Result
            
    Set drg = dlrrg.EntireRow.Columns(dvCol)
    drg.Value = dvData

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you have two nested For loops, which depending on the size of the dataset you're working with, it will likely continue to be an issue on the time it takes to complete the task. The more rows you have, the longer it will take to complete the tasks.

One possible solution that you might want to consider looking into is using power query to blend/merge/append and clean data. Then use VBA to do what Power Query doesn't do very well.

I've spent many years avoiding looking at PQ as a solution to these problems and was a VBA guy all the way, but now when I come across these types of problems,I would look at PQ first over VBA.

Comment: Thank you @Perry Moen but cannot use PQ for this